# Why do I have the talkative badge?

Tags: discussion, support

I've talked in chat a **little**.  Pretty sure not 10 messages, not recently, and I don't think I've ever been starred.  Can someone tell me why I suddenly got this badge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You actually have [eleven chat messages on chat.MSO](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152101/john?tab=recent), one of which is starred. This meets the [requirements for the Talkative badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/130/talkative), so you've been (rightfully) awarded it.

Comment: Huh.  Wow so I do.  How did you get to that?

Comment: @John If you visit chat, you can click your username in the list of links at the top of the page to visit your profile. It has various information about your chat activities, including a tab for your recent messages. There's also a list of chat users available by clicking the "x users active" link, which is how I found your profile to pull up that information.

Comment: Wow.  Learn something new about SE everyday.  Thanks!